# Magento: Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I'm installing Magento on Amazons AWS Lightsail system. I've installed NGINX, MySQL & PHP

But I keep getting this error:

```
2018/11/11 11:31:14 [error] 24035#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP     message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:384
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<?xml version="...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom.php(70): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<?xml version="...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, 'xsi:type', NULL)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(149): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom->_createConfigMerger('Magento\\Framewo...', '<?xml ve
rsion="...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(130): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(275): Magento\Frame
work\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('primary')
#5 /var" while reading response header from upstream, client: 118.209.48.25, server: tangopop.com.au, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "XX.XXX.XX.XXX"
```

Installed modules:

```
DOM     Christian Stocker, Rob Richards, Marcus Boerger 
xmlrpc
core library version    xmlrpc-epi v. 0.54
php extension version   7.2.11-4+0~20181106031710.10+jessie~1.gbp789850
author  Dan Libby
homepage    http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by     Epinions.com 
LIBXML, SimpleXML, XML, XMLReader, xmlrpc, XMLWriter
```

PHP Info Available: http://13.239.86.161/info.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the `php-dom` and `php-xml` packages, however it looks like from you PHP info. that you have done so. If you are on Debian or Ubuntu you can make sure by running `apt install php-dom php-xml`

You likely need to restart PHP FPM or Apache for the changes to take effect - eg. `systemctl restart php-fpm` or `systemctl restart apache2` (or `systemctl restart httpd`)

Answer (score 0):

yes, one have to install 'php-dom php-xml' using the command "sudo yum install php-dom php-xml" on the putty for ec2-user.
I installed using the command **sudo yum install php-dom php-xml**
It works for me like a charm.